# How to add condition to this Regex?

Tags: regex, angular, ionic-framework, angular6

How to add a condition where if the first character is 4 then 16 digits and if 3 then 15 digits?

this is what i tried so far:

```
<ion-input
            ngModel name="CNumber"
            required 
            (ionChange)="C_number($event.target.value)" 
            (ionInput)="C_number($event.target.value)"  
            maxlength="{{Maxlength}}"
            type="tel"
            pattern="^(4)[0-9]{15}$"
            >
```

`^(4)[0-9]{15}`

this will accept if the first is 4 and allows 16 characters, but how to add starting digit 3 and when so it accepts 15 characters only?

Comment: Use an alternation `^(?:4[0-9]{15}|3[0-9]{14})$` matching either one of the options. https://regex101.com/r/xw2biW/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try simple.alternative:

```
^((4)[0-9]{15})|((3)[0-9]{14})$
```

Comment: what if i want it to also accept space " ".

Comment: you can experiment here: https://regex101.com/r/qH52Xr/1